# How can I convert this date format to the ISO date format?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet with a list of dates in the format `25th Jan`. I'd like to convert these to ISO format, ie `YYYY-MM-DD`. The year will in all cases be 2016. Is there some magic equation-foo that will do this easily?

Comment: are they not formatted as date already? Can you go to format cells and pick that format?

Answer (score 2):

If your data is already in **Date** format, then just re-format the cells *(  Raystafarian's suggestion)*.  If your data is **Text**, then with data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=DATEVALUE(RIGHT(A1,3) & "-" & LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-6))
```

and format **B1**:

[image]